# Ember.js Chosen integration

Tags: ember.js, jquery-chosen

I've done a sample Ember.js integration with Chosen (https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen)

**Coffeescript:**

```
App.ChosenSelectView = Em.Select.extend({
  didInsertElement: ->
    @_super()
    @$().chosen()
    # Assumes optionLabelPath is something like "content.name"
    @addObserver(@get("optionLabelPath").replace(/^content/, "content.@each"), ->  @contentDidChange())
  contentDidChange: ->
    # 2 ticks until DOM update
    Em.run.next(this, (-> Em.run.next(this, (-> @$().trigger("liszt:updated")))))
})
```

The thing that bothers me is I don't have a good idea about how much time do I need before triggering update on the Chosen widget. From my experiments 2 run loops is ok, but maybe there is a better way for the whole thing?

Full example at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oruen/qfYPy/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is that your observer is notified kind of too early, meaning that the changes have not yet been written to the DOM.

I've hacked a little around and in the end I came up with a solution, which calls `Ember.run.sync()` before the event for the `chosen` plugin is triggered, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/dbHJb/

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="selectTmpl" >
    {{#each items tagName="select" }}
        <option {{bindAttr value="id"}} >{{name}}</option>    
    {{/each}}
</script>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.items = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    content: [Ember.Object.create({
        id: 1,
        name: 'First item'
    }), Ember.Object.create({
        id: 2,
        name: 'Second Item'
    })]
});

Ember.View.create({
    templateName: 'selectTmpl',
    itemsBinding: 'App.items',

    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.$('select').chosen();
    },

    itemsChanged: function() {
        // flush the RunLoop so changes are written to DOM?
        Ember.run.sync();
        // trigger the 'liszt:updated'
        Ember.run.next(this, function() {
            this.$('select').trigger('liszt:updated');
        });
    }.observes('items.@each.name')
}).append();

Ember.run.later(function() {
    // always use Ember.js methods to acces properties, so it should be 
    // `App.items.objectAt(0)` instead of `App.items.content[0]`
    App.items.objectAt(0).set('name', '1st Item');
}, 1000);​
```

Comment: I wonder if there is you need all Ember.run.* calls in your code. I removed them and it works. Did I miss something ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think run.sync() approach given is better then guessing number of loops before complete synchronization.

Answer (score 4):

Michael Grosser posted his working ChosenSelectView here: http://grosser.it/2012/05/05/a-chosen-js-select-filled-via-ember-js

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: As of Ember.js 1.0.0.rc4 this does not work as a drop in replacement for Ember.Select, If you can get it working please post the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you on Ember 1.0 and Chosen v0.12:

**JavaScript:**

```
App.ChosenSelect = Ember.Select.extend({
   chosenOptions: {width:'100%', placeholder_text_multiple: 'Select Editors', search_contains: true},
   multiple:true,
   attributeBindings:['multiple'],

   didInsertElement: function(){
    var view = this;
    this._super();
    view.$().chosen(view.get('chosenOptions'));

    // observes for new changes on options to trigger an update on Chosen 
    return this.addObserver(this.get("optionLabelPath").replace(/^content/, "content.@each"), function() {
      return this.rerenderChosen();
    });

  },
  _closeChosen: function(){
    // trigger escape to close chosen
    this.$().next('.chzn-container-active').find('input').trigger({type:'keyup', which:27});
  },

 rerenderChosen: function() {
    this.$().trigger('chosen:updated');
  }
});
```

**Handlebars:**

```
{{view App.ChosenSelect
    contentBinding="options"
    valueBinding="selectedOption"
    optionLabelPath="content.name"
}}
```

Comment: This is not handling value binding. For example if I call method rollback on my model chosen value is not changed.