# What is the proper approach to refreshing jQuery bindings in an Ember.js view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have an Ember.js app that has a `Checklist` model, where each Checklist has many `Checkitems`.  (A variant of the classic ToDo app, but with multiple TodoLists.)

In the top-most view, the user sees a listing of all available checklists to the left.  When a checklist is selected, the corresponding checkitems appear to the right.

The checkitems on the right side are drag sortable.  I'm using [this html5sortable library](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-html5sortable/) to handle drag sorting.  It's like the classic jQueryUI version, but less clunky.

Upon initial loading of the app, the sortable list works fine.  However, if the list of checkitems changes (either because a checkitem is marked as complete, a new checkitem is added, changes to an existing check item are saved, or another checklist is selected on the left), the binding to html5sortable is lost.

When the app first loads, I have a view called `App.CheckitemsPendingTableView`:

```
App.CheckitemsPendingTableView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'app/templates/checkitems/checkitemsPendingTable',
  classNames: ['checkitems-list', 'sortable', 'list'],
  tagName: 'ul',

  didInsertElement: function() {
    this._super();
    $('ul.sortable').sortable();
    console.log('CheckitemsPendingTableView has been inserted in the DOM and is bound to sortable.  At this point, drag-sorting of the list is working fine.');
  }
});
```

The corresponding template is called `checkitemsPendingTable.handlebars` and it looks like this:

```
{{#each content}}
  {{view App.CheckitemSingleView checkitemBinding="this"}}
{{/each}}
```

And for good measure, the controller that feeds the `content` attribute for that view is `App.checkitemsController.remainingItems`:

```
App.checkitemsController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
  content:[],

  ...snip...

  remainingItems: function() {
    var checkitems = this.get('content');
    var sortedCheckitems = checkitems.filterProperty('isDone', false).sort(function(a,b) {
                            return a.get('position') - b.get('position');
                          });
    return sortedCheckitems;
  }.property('content.@each.isDone'),

  ...snip...

});
```

The content attribute of the `checkitemsController` is driven by the `checklistsController`:

```
App.checklistsController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
  content: App.store.findAll(App.Checklist),

  selectedChanged: function() {
    var checklist = this.get('selected');
    var checkitems = checklist.get('checkitems');
    App.checkitemsController.set('checklist', checklist);
    App.checkitemsController.set('content', checkitems);
  }.observes('selected')
});
```

(You may have noticed that this controller pulls its data from a Rails backend via ember-data.  This shouldn't matter for the current issue, though.)

The view for the left-hand side's menu is called `checklistsView`.  It has a child view called `checklistSingleView` that is rendered for each of the checklists:

```
App.ChecklistSingleView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'app/templates/checklists/checklistSingle',
  classNames:   ['menu-item'],
  tagName: 'tr',

  ...snip...

  chooseList: function() {
    var checklists = App.checklistsController.get('content');
    checklists.setEach('isActive', false);
    var checklist = this.get('checklist');
    checklist.set('isActive', true);
    App.checklistsController.set('selected', checklist);
  }

  ...snip...

});
```

And, finally, the corresponding template `checklistSingle.handlebars` contains a link that is tied to the `chooseList` by way of an action:

```
<a href="#" {{action "chooseList"}}>{{checklist.name}}</a>
```

So, everything above works brilliantly...until the user causes a change to the `ul` of checkitems on the right.  At that point, the binding to `html5sortable` is lost, and I cannot find a convenient place to refresh it.

The problem is that `didInsertElement` is not called again for the view that generates that `ul` (i.e., `CheckitemsPendingTableView`).  When the checklistController's `content` attribute changes, the child views dutifully adjust to reflect the currently-selected list of checkitems.  However, the original binding to `sortable()` is lost, and there is no apparent hook for re-binding to `sortable()` via jQuery.

I can't re-bind on the child view of `CheckitemsPendingTableView`, since that would repeat for every instance of a checkitem in the currently-selected list.  I can't rebind from the controllers or models, since they will attempt to bind before the DOM update is completed.

I'm sure I'm just thinking about this incorrectly.  I'm new to Ember.js (if it isn't wildly obvious), and am struggling to understand how this case is properly handled.

**UPDATE**

I solved this problem, by adding the following function and observer to the `App.CheckitemsPendingTableView`:

```
resetSortableTable: function() {
    $('.sortable').unbind('sortable');
    $('.sortable').sortable();
    console.log('Sort reset by CheckitemsPendingTableView');
  },

itemsChanged: function() {
    console.log('itemsChanged caught in CheckitemsPendingTableView');
    // flush the RunLoop so changes are written to DOM
    Ember.run.sync();
    Ember.run.next(this, function() {
        this.resetSortableTable();
    });
  }.observes('content.@each')
```

I based my solution on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9981788/1293561).  I'm a little worried that it's not a great solution, since it seems to be making assumptions about the DOM completing during a run loop iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoa! Kind of detailed question...

I think your issue comes from html5sortable plugin: it uses JQuery's `bind` method to attach handlers directly on living elements. As those elements disappear/evolve under Ember control, the binding are lost.

The plugin should better use JQuery's `on` method to bind handlers, as specified [in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

Comment: Thanks for reading, Mike!  I considered going with `on`, but found a workaround meanwhile (see update to my original question).

Comment: You're welcome. Indeed, the workaround you found sounds really crappy... :-P